# did not unload c# dll after couninitialize

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I loaded c# dll using CoInitialize() and CoCreateInstance().

After calling c# function, also called CoUninitialize() function.

C# dll was registered with regasm.exe

```
reg_asm.exe /tlb SampleDll.dll
```

in c++, I loaded as following.

```
ISampleDll* instance_;

HRESULT hrSample = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hrSample)) {
  return 0;
}

CLSID cls;
if (!SUCCEEDED(CLSIDFromProgID(L"SampleDll.Class1", &cls))) {
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}

hrSample = CoCreateInstance(cls, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
IID_ISampleDll, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&instance_));
if (S_OK != hrSample) {
  return 0;
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hrSample)) {
  if (instance_ != NULL) {
    instance_->Release();
    instance_ = NULL;
  }

  CoUninitialize();
}
```

I found that after calling CoUninitialize(), can not unload c# dll, too.
while after calling CoCreateInstance(), my program's memory increases.

How can I unload c# dll from memory?
Can CoUninitialize() function unload c# dll?

Comment: Depends.  Though you have released the .NET COM object and satisfied COM reference counting, .NET reference counting may be still in play.  Is the object a singleton?  Does it create other objects? Are these other objects referencing it.  Are any of these .NET objects acting as servers (not necessarily COM-related)?

Comment: Can you post the code for `SampleDll.Class1`?